# SwiftUI: swipe actions pass data to next view from button action

Tags: swiftui

I'm showing a `List` of TODOs and one of the swipe action is to edit it on another view:

```swift
// …
TodoItemView(todo)
  .swipeActions {
    // …
    Button("Edit") {
      toBeEdit = todo
      showEditTodo.toggle()
    }
  }
```

at the end I have a sheet for it:

```swift
// …
.sheet(isPresented: $showEditTodo) {
    EditTodoView($toBeEdit)
}
```

I wonder if there's a more elegant way of doing this? The fact that `toBeEdit` is assigned in one place but used (and expected to be non-nil) in another place makes me feeling a bit lost, compared to non-SwiftUI code where you show the edit screen just in the action with the `todo` object.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`